# Trying to understand specific print statement

Tags: java, binary

If I had the print statement: System.out.println(x & 0x00000001);
Assuming int x = -1;

Why does it print 1?

I understand number systems such as binary, hexadecimal and even some octal. What I don't quite understand is the use of the "&" within the print statement and what it's actually doing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int x = -1;
    System.out.println(x & 0x00000001);
}
```

expected results: "I dont quite know"

results: 1

Comment: It is obvious that 0x00000001 represented as a decimal is 1 but other then that I am confused by the output.

Answer (score 1):

The binary representation of -1 is (read about 2's complement to learn more about that):

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

The binary representation of 0x00000001 is:

```
00000000000000000000000000000001
```

when you bit-wise AND the two numbers you get

```
00000000000000000000000000000001
```

Hence the output is 1.

Comment: I do understand how to do the 2's complement, you inverse all the bits and add 1 to its value. But I don't get how the 8-bit representation of 1 is: 00000000000000000000000000000001 and what the & symbol means.

Comment: @DooperDank it's not an 8-bit representation. `0x00000001` is an `int` literal, so it has 32 bits. `&` means bit-wise AND, which means you perform AND on each pair of corresponding bits.

Comment: That's right in java and int is 32 bits, thank you for the help!